# How do I query an Elasticsearch nested document within an inner object?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to filter on a field within a [nested document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in an Elasticsearch query (ES 5.6.2). The nested document is itself a field within an inner object of the main document. The mapping looks like this:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "container": {
            "properties": {
                "host": {
                    "properties": {
                        "tags_nested": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "tag_key": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "tag_val": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to filter on `host.tags_nested.tag_keys`, but I can't figure out the right syntax to access the nested `tags_nested` document within the `host` inner object. I tried the following query, which doesn't return any results, when I know there are some that should match:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "host.tags_nested",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "host.tags_nested.tag_key": "example_key"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the [ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html), you can do a `nested` query to query within a nested doc, by passing a `path` which corresponds to the field name of the nested doc. But this seems not to work when the `path` is within an inner object and needs to be accessed using dot notation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) searches for exact words which we specify. So, for that use `fieldname.keyword` because keyword stores exact text as we index them.

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "host.tags_nested",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "host.tags_nested.tag_key.keyword": "example_key"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```